# What is Microsoft Dynamics AX?

Tags: axapta

I am .net developer. I have no idea about Microsoft Dynamics AX. can any one suggest what is MS Dynamic Ax. and for what purpose. how to install that in my computer. i mean is there any setup. and One sample application regarding morph x and x++. Please can you share any document regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamics AX is an ERP system not a desktop application.  MorphX is Dynamics AX's native IDE and X++ is the language used to develop.  X++ is an object oriented language similar to Java or C#.  This is a very broad question with no simple way to answer.  If you do not work at a Microsoft partner or company that runs AX, you don't have much of a chance of exploring the platform.  Sorry, wish I had more to help.